# What is the relationship between the mass and the cross in precise terms?

Tags: catholicism, communion, priesthood, mass, sacrifice

I have read that during a mass the sacrifice of the cross is "re-presented" which is to say "presented again", which implies that the single sacrifice of the cross is just neatly packaged up and presented to the father - so the sacrifice only happened once, 2000 years ago, but the "presentation" or "offering" of that sacrifice is repeated many times and perpetuated throughout the ages.

But then again I have read in other places that the sacrifice of the mass is literally the same sacrifice as the sacrifice of the cross. Which is to say, being present at mass is ontologically equivalent to being present at the foot of the cross. Or in other words, a Catholic mass is not merely the "offering" or "presentation" of a previously performed sacrifice - *it is in actual fact the performance of the sacrifice itself*; The sacrifice of Christ is not merely being "offered up", he is instead literally being sacrificed before our eyes. I find that this understanding of things is hard to wrap my head around (It would seem that the sacrifice is being repeated in this case, and that the protestant criticism that catholics are "re-sacrificing" christ might have something to it). Nevertheless I find it very important for my faith walk, because keeping this understanding in mind really brings the mass to life for me.

With this preamble in mind, please clarify the following yes/no questions concerning a Catholic mass:

1. Does Jesus "die" during the mass?
2. Does Jesus die "again" during the mass?
3. Is the sacrifice of Christ repeated during the mass?
4. Is the one sacrifice of Christ performed once for all 2000 years ago merely packaged up and "offered to the father again" during mass, or is the sacrifice of the cross literally performed before our eyes during a mass?
5. Is the sacrifice of the mass a different and completely separate sacrifice to the sacrifice of Christ on the cross?

Comment: Are you asking about the relationship between Mass and Crucifix, or Mass and Cross?  Your title and your text don't quite match.  Re-presented means "made present again."  (Or so I have had it explained).   I don't have time for an answer just now, but maybe tomorrow.  There's a lot going on in your question, ,and it does not lend itself to a short answer.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour).

For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers on this site.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73643/discussion-on-question-by-chuck-butch-what-is-the-relationship-between-the-mass).

Answer (score 4):

Point 1.  Does Jesus "Die" During the Mass

No, he does not, Jesus is in his Glorified State sitting at the Right hand of the father constantly interceding in our behalf, the one true intercessor between Man and and God the Father.

Point 2. Does Jesus die "Again" during the Mass

No, Jesus died for our sins once and for all (time) 2000 years ago. In his one sacrifice he died for all men who ever lived, whoever is living and who ever will live. His sacrifice and his alone made Satisfaction for all man kind and has not limit in it's Merit.  Christ died once for everyone, wether or not you accept this free gift, he died for you only the once.

Point 3. Is the sacrifice of Christ repeated during the mass?

No, despite what many anti-catholic Christians state, Christ is not re-sacrificed during the Mass.  Through the liturgy Catholics enter into the once true sacrifice at Calvary, they enter into the what is identified as the New Covenant, The Eucharistic Celebration.  "This is my blood of the covenant which is poured out for many." "For as often as you shall eat this bread and drink the chalice, you shall shew the death of the Lord, until he come."  I Think the Eucharist is celebrated about every 4 minutes around the Globe.  That's often.

Point 4. Is the one sacrifice of Christ performed once for all 2000 years ago merely packaged up and "offered to the father again" during mass, or is the sacrifice of the cross literally performed before our eyes during a mass?

Yes and No.  During the Mass the sacrifice is re-pressented not represented.  Its s a spiritual reality but that does not mean it is not real. At mass we biblically unite ourselves to the one and only sacrifice that is before the father at all times. It is a un-bloody Sacrifice but a sacrifice non-the-less, we are offering up to the father that very same sacrifice, uniting ourselves to it along with our thanks, praise and charity, with the angels in heaven and every other mass that has happened in the past present and future with every Catholic Christian that ever lived, are living or will live. Unlike Protestants who worship a risen Christ, we, as Saint Paul says "Preach Christ Crucified".  Each and every Eucharistic celebration.  Bishop Fulton Sheen once said "The Gospel that has removed Christ from the Cross is demonic" The Cross is the Ultimate example of Love.

Point 5. Is the sacrifice of the mass a different and completely separate sacrifice to the sacrifice of Christ on the cross?

No.  It is the one and same sacrifice.  Christ is not suffering again, as anti-catholics like R.C. Sproul and others separated from the Truth like to say.  The Mass is a Participation in that one Sacrifice.  This is what we are called to "do".  Christ says "Do This"  many times in scripture.